# Npgsql C# wcf app hangs on command.ExecuteReader()

Tags: npgsql

multi threaded npgsql app suffers from db problem that I can reproduce every time.

Running 3 parallel login requests  to app destabilizes app and then when I send batch (runs several queries) some ExecuteReader hangs.

Call to command.ExecuteReader() never returns, only when CommandTimeout expires (60 seconds).

Stack trace from the hanging call:

```
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.dll!System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags socketFlags, out System.Net.Sockets.SocketError errorCode) Unknown
    System.dll!System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags socketFlags)   Unknown
    System.dll!System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size)   Unknown
    Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlReadBuffer.Ensure.__EnsureLong|0() Line 150 C#
    Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlReadBuffer.Ensure(int count, bool async, bool dontBreakOnTimeouts) Line 116 C#
    Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadMessage.__ReadMessageLong|0(Npgsql.DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode2, bool readingNotifications2, bool isReadingPrependedMessage) Line 954   C#
    Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadMessage(bool async, Npgsql.DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, bool readingNotifications) Line 923 C#
    Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(bool async, bool isConsuming) Line 444    C#
    [Resuming Async Method] 
    mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<bool>.Start<Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.<NextResult>d__46>(ref Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.<NextResult>d__46 stateMachine)  Unknown
    Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult() Line 332    C#
    Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior, bool async, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Line 1218   C#
    Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior) Line 1130 C#
    Npgsql.dll!Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior) Line 1111   C#
>   xyz.PostgresDBConnection.ExecReader(Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand comm) Line 279 C#
```

Comment: The used version of Npgsql is we tried several versions from the 3.x.x as well as the latest 4.0.4. We even tried to compile npgsql dll hotfix/3.2.8 from github but the same issue occurs.

Comment: Sounds like you may be trying to use the same connection concurrently from multiple threads - that would be the first place to look. Each connection may only be used by one threat a time.

Comment: Hello Shay Rojansky My every thread creates it's own connection using `this.conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
                    this.conn.Open();`

Comment: I've added mutex so that every thread can use their separate NpgsqlConnection only once at a time but this does not appear to affect the problem.

Comment: Github issue: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2262

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely a concurrency issue, where multiple threads are accessing the same connection at the same time.

Npgsql comes with built-in connection pool, like other database drivers. Assuming you haven't disabled this, then the recommended practice is to create a new NpgsqlConnection object each time you want to use the database, and to call `Open()` on it. When you're done, dispose the connection. Do not attempt to reuse the connection object as that has very little value and is prone to concurrency issues.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the culprit is the following extremely slow query (on table with 31259 rows):

```
SELECT Item.id, Item.data FROM Item 
INNER JOIN Item AS it ON item.id = Item.id AND item.data = Item.data 
AND item.data2 <> Item.data2 LIMIT 1
```

Npgsql was however not stuck on this query but different one but the cause is this query.

I replaced it with different equivalent query:

```
SELECT Item.id, Item.data FROM Item
GROUP BY Item.id, Item.data
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Item.data2) > 1
LIMIT 1
```

and the problem appears to be solved.